Despliegue barato de laravel con, postgresql y un servicio de almacenamiento de archivos
alguien me podría recomendar algún servicio o algunos, donde pueda desplegar una aplicación mvc de laravel y un servicio de base de datos y otro de almacenamiento de archivos?.
la aplicación es interna para una empresa y tendrá poco uso. estaba pensando en usar aws ec2 para desplegar la app de laravel y tal vez ahí mismo configurar la base de datos o usar aparte rds y el s3 para almacenar archivos, usando la free tier de 1 año de aws. pero no sé si haya algunas otras opciones que a la larga puedan ser más baratas

Buenas, te comento.
Echale un ojo a render.com , ahi tienes soporte para Laravel gratuito y lo he usado para proyectos con caracteristicas similares a las tuyas, donde habra pocos clientes y poco trafico en general y el coste parte de cero euros, si lo tienes que ampliar pues ya dependera de ti.
Aqui, tambien tendras hosting gratuito para Postgresql, muy sencillo de configurar tambien.
